# Exclude a property from unobstrusive client Validation with MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a class User, that have an Email property, like that :

```
public class User : Entity
{       
...
    [Display(Name = "Email"), Required(ErrorMessage = "Required."), Remote("EmailExists", "User", ErrorMessage = "Email already in Use.")]
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
...
}
```

My View Create works fine with all the validation ...
But in my view Edit, my Email texbox is **Readonly**, so The user cant change the email...

The problem is my Remote validation *EmailExists* keeps firing...

Is there a way to exclude the Email client validation just in that case? Or maybe another solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution would be to render Email as text content(span, p, etc) in that particular case -  validations would not fire. This would be best accomplished with editor templates.  But if you don't wish to, you could use some javascript to remove rules on client side. Take a look at [Plugins/Validation/rules](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22remove.22rules) - you would remove rule when textbox is readonly. But for me the first way is preferred option

Answer (score 1):

I think that the easier way is to disable the field in the client instead of using readonly. The validate plugin doesn't take in account disabled fields.

Comment: The form fields are easily tampered, so if the field must be readonly you just have to take in account at the controller, updating the email only if it's a  new user.

Answer (score 0):

You could use different ViewModels for the edit and create views and only apply the Remote attribute to view model associated with the create view or call some other remote validation logic for the view model associated with the edit view.